# AWS IAM permissions needed to view the metrics on metric Explorer in custom dashboard

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

I have created a user group and attached AWS Managed Policy: CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess to a group. I have created a custom dashboard to monitor my resources and added few explorer's to it. All the widgets are access but explorer's is throwing **permission error: You don't have permission to access the tags and resources needed to generate the charts. To get the right access, contact your administrator.** The explorer fetches the data using resource tag and that too is throwing **error: Tags and properties in red are not available for the selected metrics.**

I have tried TagEditor, Resource Group Tagging describeTags, listResourceTags of Elastic BeanStalk, EC2, EC2 autoscaling group, etc using a customer managed policy which I created. I have also used condition for a specific EBS environment name.

Help me in writing my customer managed policy.

**CloudWatchReadOnlyAccess**

````
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Action": [
        "autoscaling:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:Describe*",
        "cloudwatch:Get*",
        "cloudwatch:List*",
        "logs:Get*",
        "logs:Describe*",
        "sns:Get*",
        "sns:List*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You need to add/allow the below "Action" in your policy :

---

### "tag:GetResources"